# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout with Google Play testing

Tags: c#, android

I finished my app and have successfully uploaded it to Google play pending release.  Google play reports 6 errors and issues running on some (all?) devices.  The app runs flawlessly on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S6), but apparently not on a lot of the devices Google Play Console uses to test apps.  I've search all over for an answer, but can find nothing.  The main error is

```
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

This is apparently related to the `AppCompat` library.  I have absolutely no clue as to what this is or how to fix it.  Does any one here know what this is and how to fix it?

For reference, this is part of the error report I got on the Google Play console (it's too big to post all of it):

```
03-04 21:34:21.218: I/MonoDroid(28541): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541): Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ---> Java.Lang.ReflectiveOperationException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.ReflectiveOperationException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/chatty(28541): uid=10231(u0_a231) my.First.App.Release identical 1 line
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <6a3b839ddb6b42bcb33692678ca4ec56>:0 
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <6a3b839ddb6b42bcb33692678ca4ec56>:0 
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (System.Int32 layoutResID) [0x00022] in <5af9d8a8d6254f07b185528e533ea266>:0 
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   at OML_Android.CreateAccount.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00014] in <0439a8318b6d4a21b5c7d1d10ab91f1f>:0 
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <5af9d8a8d6254f07b185528e533ea266>:0 
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.3(intptr,intptr,intptr)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:461)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2737)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at md52aa0401196c9e7bb16cfdc0cc15d2963.CreateAccount.n_onCreate(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at md52aa0401196c9e7bb16cfdc0cc15d2963.CreateAccount.onCreate(CreateAccount.java:29)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:20)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:169)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:161)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:77)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:19)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:3)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:97)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:206)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:200)
03-04 21:34:21.228: I/MonoDroid(28541):     ... 42 more
03-04 21:34:21.229: E/AndroidJUnitRunner(28541): An unhandled exception was thrown by the app.
03-04 21:34:21.231: I/AndroidJUnitRunner(28541): Bringing down the entire Instrumentation process.
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541): Exception encountered by: md52aa0401196c9e7bb16cfdc0cc15d2963.CreateAccount@26c9b3c. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:461)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2737)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at md52aa0401196c9e7bb16cfdc0cc15d2963.CreateAccount.n_onCreate(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at md52aa0401196c9e7bb16cfdc0cc15d2963.CreateAccount.onCreate(CreateAccount.java:29)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:187)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:20)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:169)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:161)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:77)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:19)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:3)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:97)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:206)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:200)
03-04 21:34:21.231: E/MonitoringInstr(28541):   ... 42 more
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):   Thread[main,5,main]
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1536)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1586)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.d(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:163)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.onException(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:160)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onException(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:135)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2954)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:20)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:169)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:161)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:77)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:19)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:3)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:97)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):   Thread[ReferenceQueueDaemon,5,system]
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:178)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):   Thread[Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner,5,main]
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2135)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:868)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1021)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:232)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished(RemotePlatform.java:17)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.CrawlPlatform.testEntry(CrawlPlatform.java:2)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.ck.d.b(FrameworkMethod.java:2)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.cc.c.a(ReflectiveCallable.java:2)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.ck.e.a(FrameworkMethod.java:6)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.ce.g.a(InvokeMethod.java:5)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.a(RunBefores.java:16)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.cj.a.a(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:2)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.cj.b.a(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:115)
03-04 21:34:21.233: E/THREAD_STATE(28541):     androidx.test.too
```

Comment: Can you please post your layout file as well? Thank you!

Comment: Which layout file?  I have a ton.

Comment: LOL. I can see another actually in your logcat. `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.`

Comment: Looks like some device with lower API versions could not load the theme that you are using.

Comment: @Reaz Murshed Yeah, I saw that.  Looking into it now.  I think I may have an answer.  Testing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had mentioned in my question, the issue was with the `AppCompat` library.  All my activities were created by extending `Activity`, when using the `AppCompat` library, the activities need to extend `AppCompatActivity`.  For example:

```
public class MYActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

I made that change and resubmitted the app to Google Console, they report it's ready to distribute, so issue resolved.